# REGEX: remove comma at the end of the following date pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting the following JSON of an API:

```
{
  "things": [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "bla": "blablablabla",
      "summary": "blablablabla",
      "date": "11/12/2016",
    },
    {
      "id": 101,
      "bla": "blablablabla",
      "summary": "blablablabla",
      "date": "02/05/2017",
    },
    {
      "id": 102,
      "bla": "blablablabla",
      "summary": "blablablabla",
      "date": "03/03/2017",
    },
    {
      "id": 103,
      "bla": "blablablabla",
      "summary": "blablablabla",
      "date": "12/04/2017",
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see there's a typo in this json, because the comma after the date, is an error, there is a way to remove this comma after every date?

Comment: [`("date"\s*:\s*"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}")\s*,`](https://regex101.com/r/2alKVs/2) replace with `$1`

Comment: is that the format you have or is it without whitespace?

Comment: Do you have access to change it at the server?

Comment: No I don't have access to the server

Comment: btw, you do not get a [JSON](http://json.org/) compliant string. maybe you have a look to the api or ask the vendor for getting a standard string.

Comment: Yes totally agree, but I have to wait until monday.

Answer (score 3):

Replace comma character followed by newline and space characters followed by `}`

```
str.replace(/,(?=[\n\s]+})/g, "")
```

Comment: This is the better answer, as the problem is not that a comma appears after the "date" pair, but that a comma appears before a closing brace.

Comment: @JonathanM I couldn't agree more. My brain just didn't process that distinction at first.

Comment: `\n` is part of `\s` already, so may be simplified to `/,(?=\s*})/g`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following RegEx: `("date": "[0-9\/]*"),`

```
preg_replace("/("date": "[0-9\/]*"),/", "$1", $json);
```

We search for `"date": "`, then an endless amount of any digit from 0-9 OR slashes, which will take us all the way up to the final quotation mark. In the pattern, we include this quotation mark. From the first to the last quotation mark, is all included in parenthesis so that it is a group match (We will call "Group 1"), and then we verify it ends with a comma `,`. Once we verify this, we replace the whole selection with just "Group 1", so that the comma is removed from the string.

You can see a more step-by-step walkthrough [on regex101](https://regex101.com/).